# If $f$ is a bijection of $A$ onto $B$ show $f^{-1}$ is a bijection of $B$ onto $A$

Tags: real-analysis, elementary-set-theory, alternative-proof

If this is a duplicate you can close this post.

> Introduction to Real Analysis (Robert G. Bartle) 18. (b)
>
> If $f$ is a bijection of $A$ onto $B$, show that $f^{-1}$ is a bijection of $B$ onto $A$.

Attempt:

If $f$ is a bijection $A$ onto $B$ then if $x\in A$ then $f(x)\in B$ and if $x_1\neq x_2$ then $f(x_1)\neq f(x_2)$.

By definition of inverse, $f^{-1}:=\left\{(f(a),a): B\times A, (a,f(a))\in f \right\}$, so $f^{-1}$ is a surjection from $B$ to $A$. Moreover if $f(x_1)\neq f(x_2)$ then $x_1\neq x_2$ implying injection since $f$ is already injective hence $f^{-1}$ is injective. Since $f^{-1}$ is injective and surjective $f^{-1}$ is also bijective.

I doubt I’m correct. For one, I want the final step to be if $x_1\neq x_2$ then $f^{-1}(x_1)\neq f^{-1}(x_2)$. How do we do this?

Answer (score 1):

For every $y\in B$ **there is** a **unique** $x_y\in A$ such that $f(x_y)=y$.

We then have $f^{-1}(\{y\})= \{t\in A : f(t) = y\} =\{ x_y\}$. So, $f^{-1}$ is a function and $f^{-1}(y)=x_y$.

If $f^{-1}(y_1) = f^{-1}(y_2)$, then  ${x_{y_1}} = {x_{y_2}}$. Applying $f$ on both sides of the equality, we get $y_1 = y_2$. This proves injectivity.

Given an arbitrary $x \in A$, we have $f^{-1}({f(x)}) =x_{f(x)}=x$. This proves surjectivity.

Comment: Is my proof correct or were there mistakes?

Comment: It doesn't look correct (in your first line you seem to misstate surjectivity definition of f; also injectivity proof is confusing). My first phrase is the key. The 'there is' part is surjectivity of f. The 'unique' part states the injectivity of f (you can't have two different x's 'hitting' the same y via f). We then show the same things for $f^{-1}$, noting first that it is a function (associates only one single x in A to a given y in B, as in my second line).

Answer (score 0):

Showing that if $x \neq y$ then $f^{-1}(x)\neq f^{-1}(y)$ is equivalent to prove that if $f^{-1}(x) = f^{-1}(y)$ then $x=y$. But if $f^{-1}(x) = f^{-1}(y)$ then the images by $f$ must be equal, so $f(f^{-1}(x)) = x = y = f(f^{-1}(y))$.